# Libgdx lwjgl3 crash on start

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I switched on lwjgl3 from lwjgl2 and can't run game with that.

Full code:

```
Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
config.setWindowedMode(1280, 720);
new Lwjgl3Application(new MyGdxGame(), config);
```

Crash log: 
https://pastebin.com/0N1tAYRk

Comment: show your root `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: Are you mixing classes from LWJGL 2 and 3? Do you have old class files in your project that were compiled with the old version? Make sure all your libraries are compatible (check the versions) and re-compile your entire project.

Comment: possible reason you're mixing LWJGL 2 and 3. Make sure you're not using any artifact/jar that rely on LWJGL 2

Comment: @AbhishekAryan https://pastebin.com/cE0XwFjR

Comment: @Jesper Intellij Idea can't find occurrences to "lwjgl" except of my lwjgl3 and one lwjgl in core projects `build.gradle`. Problem with that occurrence in core?

Answer (score 2):

GLFW windows may only be created on the main thread and that thread must be the first thread in the process.

Run the JVM with `-XstartOnFirstThread`

If you're using IntellijIDEA/Android Studio

Go to Run -> Edit Configuration -> Click to your desktop config ->Configuration Tab -> VM Options -> Paste `-XstartOnFirstThread` -> Click apply -> Ok and then run.

Comment: which OS you're using ?

Comment: Window 7
Java 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0):

There was the same problem with android studio 4.2.1, it helped me in the `build.gradle` file, in the `"dependencies"` block, change:

```
"com.PROJECT_NAME.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
```

to

```
"com.PROJECT_NAME.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
```